# Solve a set of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am not an expert in Mathematica and I am trying to solve simultaneously the following equations.

```
VoBB = (625 dreal)/(11 (1 - dreal)) - 25/28 (1.008 + 0.075 (784/(625 (1 - dreal)^2) + (15625 dreal^2)/13068) + 0.013 (1 - dreal) (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 0.0333333 dreal (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
       33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + (31 (625/11 + VoBB))/40000 + (43 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (625/11 + VoBB))/80000 + (27 (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) (625/11 + VoBB))/40000 + 8.31434 dreal^0.692 (1.24608 dreal + 
    0.00578199 (1 - dreal) VoBB^1.33));

VoBt = 625/(11 (1 - dreal)) - 25/28 (1.008 + 0.075 (784/(625 (1 - dreal)^2) + (15625 dreal^2)/13068) + 0.013 (1 - dreal) (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (-((125 dreal)/33) +  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
      1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 0.0333333 dreal (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 8.31434 dreal^0.692 (1.24608 dreal + 0.00578199 (1 - dreal) (625/11 - VoBt)^1.33) + (31 VoBt)/40000 + (43 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) VoBt)/80000 + (27 (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) VoBt)/40000);

625 = VoBB + VoBt;
```

where dreal,VoBB and VoBt are the variables.
Since they are not polynomials, Solve and NSolve don't work. I tried also FindRoot and Reduce, but I didn't get any results.

Could anyone suggest me a method how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Step 1) use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: yes I have done this, only here I put =, but while trying to solve the problem I put == of course

Comment: Do any of these variables have any restrictions on the range of allowed values e.g. are any known to be positive?

Comment: yes, thank you for noticing. They are all positve and specifically:
0<dreal<0.99, 0<VoBB<625, 0<VoBt<625

Answer (score 1):

[`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) needs higher precision and reasonable starting values.

```
eq1 = VoBB == (625 dreal)/(11 (1 - dreal)) - 
      25/28 (1.008 + 
         0.075 (784/(625 (1 - dreal)^2) + (15625 dreal^2)/13068) + 
         0.013 (1 - 
            dreal) (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 
            1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                   33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 
         0.0333333 dreal (1/
              4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 
            1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                   33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                   33))^2) + (31 (625/11 + VoBB))/
          40000 + (43 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (625/11 +
               VoBB))/
          80000 + (27 (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
              1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) (625/11 + 
              VoBB))/40000 + 
         8.31434 dreal^0.692 (1.24608 dreal + 
            0.00578199 (1 - dreal) VoBB^1.33)) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;

eq2 = VoBt == 
     625/(11 (1 - dreal)) - 
      25/28 (1.008 + 
         0.075 (784/(625 (1 - dreal)^2) + (15625 dreal^2)/13068) + 
         0.013 (1 - 
            dreal) (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 
            1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                   33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 
         0.0333333 dreal (1/
              4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 
            1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
                   33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
               1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 
         8.31434 dreal^0.692 (1.24608 dreal + 
            0.00578199 (1 - dreal) (625/11 - VoBt)^1.33) + (31 VoBt)/
          40000 + (43 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) VoBt)/
          80000 + (27 (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
              1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) VoBt)/
          40000) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;

sol = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, 
  625 == VoBB + VoBt}, {{dreal, 5}, {VoBB, 500}, {VoBt, -50}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {dreal -> 2.6863110684610678957, VoBB -> 655.93572228732459724, 
 VoBt -> -30.935722287324597235} *)

{eq1, eq2, 625 == VoBB + VoBt} /. sol

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: The fsolve and DirectSearch:-SolveEquations commands of Maple need not "reasonable starting values  {{dreal, 5}, {VoBB, 500}, {VoBt, -50}}" .

Comment: It is sometimes difficult to know the starting values. Could you tell me how can I add constraints 0<dreal<0.99, 0<VoBB<625, 0<VoBt<625?

Comment: Constraints (e.g., inequalities) can be used in [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html); however, if the constraints don't include a solution you will get `{ }` for a result.  `FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, Subscript[x, start], Subscript[x, min], Subscript[x, max]}] searches for a solution, stopping the search if x ever gets outside the range Subscript[x, min] to Subscript[x, max].` Starting values can sometimes be determined by plotting or an understanding of the problem. Your constraints do not appear consistent with these equations.

Comment: You wrote "Starting values can sometimes be determined by plotting or an understanding of the problem ". Can you kindly demonstrate how {{dreal, 5}, {VoBB, 500}, {VoBt, -50}} were found by you? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 - I used values close to those that you said Maple provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
VoBB == (625 dreal)/(11 (1 - dreal)) - 25/28 (1.008 + 
  0.075 (784/(625 (1 - dreal)^2) + (15625 dreal^2)/13068) + 
  0.013 (1 - dreal) (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 
  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 
  0.0333333 dreal (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 
  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + (31 (625/11 + VoBB))/
  40000 + (43 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33) (625/11 + VoBB))/
  80000 + (27 (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) +
  (125 dreal)/33)) (625/11 + VoBB))/40000 + 8.31434 dreal^0.692*
  (1.24608 dreal + 0.00578199 (1 - dreal) VoBB^1.33));

VoBt == 625/(11 (1 - dreal)) - 25/28 (1.008 + 0.075 (784/(625 (1 -
  dreal)^2) + (15625 dreal^2)/13068) + 0.013 (1 - dreal) (1/4 (56/(25 (1 -
  dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
  33) (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/
  33)) + (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) +
  (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 0.0333333 dreal (1/4 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) +
  (125 dreal)/33)^2 + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)*
  (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) +
  (-((125 dreal)/33) + 1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33))^2) + 
  8.31434 dreal^0.692 (1.24608 dreal + 0.00578199 (1 - dreal) (625/11 -
  VoBt)^1.33) + (31 VoBt)/40000 + (43 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) +
  (125 dreal)/33) VoBt)/80000 + (27 (-((125 dreal)/33) + 
  1/2 (56/(25 (1 - dreal)) + (125 dreal)/33)) VoBt)/40000);

sol = NMinimize[Norm[625 - (VoBB + VoBt)], {VoBB, VoBt, dreal}]
```

which instantly returns `{1.55979*10^-6, {VoBB->274.375, VoBt->350.625, dreal->-433.183}}`

and

```
VoBB + VoBt /. sol[[2]]
```

instantly returns `625.`

Comment: Maple answers $ \{ VoBB = 655.935722286923, VoBt = -30.9357222869234, dreal = 2.68631106848311 \}.$

Comment: MMA `NMinimize[Norm[VoBB - expr1] + Norm[VoBt - expr2] + Norm[625 - (VoBB + VoBt)], {VoBB, VoBt, dreal}]` returns `VoBB -> 346.456, VoBt -> 278.537, dreal -> 0.87113` With that many denominators and rational powers I expect there is a forest of solutions. Can anyone enumerate all the solutions?

Comment: Maple performs the only real solution $\{VoBB = 655.935722286924, VoBt = -30.9357222869235, dreal = 2.68631106848311\}$ by two independent ways.

Comment: Putting WorkingPrecision->12 in your NMinimize command, I obtain " NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations".

Comment: @Bill thank you very much, your solution seems to help. Specifically, I added some constraints:
NMinimize[{Norm[VoBB - expr1] + Norm[VoBt - expr2] + 
   Norm[625 - (VoBB + VoBt)], 0 < dreal < 0.99, 0 < VoBB < 625, 
  0 < VoBt < 625}, {VoBB, VoBt, dreal}]

and it gives me the results:
{30.5878, {VoBB -> 288.167, VoBt -> 334.416, dreal -> 0.849056}}
which seem somewhat correct, although VoBt+VoBB=625 is False.

Could you explain how did you choose NMinimize and Norm? I read the definitions, but I cannot understand the use here, because I don't want to find any minimum.

Comment: You wanted to find left==right. You might imagine that is like trying to minimize Abs[left-right]. The way you wrote the problem worries me, but I tried to not change what you did and showed it seemed to find values that almost exactly matched your requirements. It is VERY common for someone to get an answer and reply "yes but let me change the problem now." If I do your NMinimize then the first part of the result is 28.0758 and that says it was not able to find a solution where the sum of your three differences was ~zero. Your new problem may not have a solution or NMinimize didn't find it.